# How do you add environment variables to a python scrapy project? dotenv didn't work

Tags: python, scrapy, environment-variables, python-dotenv

I'm having trouble incorporating an IP address into a format string in my Python Scrapy project. I was trying to use python-dotenv to store sensitive information, such as server IPs, in a .env file and load it into my project, instead of hardcoding it.

I added python-dotenv to the settings.py file of my Scrapy project, but when I run a function that should use the values stored in os, I get an error saying that it can't detect dotenv. Can someone help me understand why this is happening and how to properly incorporate an IP address in a format string using python-dotenv in a Python Scrapy project?

Comment: Did you add this code to your `settings.py` file? `from dotenv import load_dotenv`
`load_dotenv()`

Comment: Did you add this code? `import os` `IP_ADDRESS = os.getenv('IP_ADDRESS')`

Comment: Can you add the full error message to your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is difficult to help figure out what you might be doing wrong with the limited information you have provided. However here is a general example of how one might use `python-dotenv` with a scrapy `settings.py` file.

First create a `.env` file and add your IP

`.env`

```
IPADDRESS = SUPERSECRETIPADDRESS
```

Finally in your `settings.py` file you need to import `dotenv` and then run `dotenv.load_dotenv()` and then you can get the ip address from the environment variable.

`settings.py`

```
import os
import dotenv

dotenv.load_dotenv()

IP_ADDRESS_SCRAPY_SETTING = os.environ["IPADDRESS"]

print(IP_ADDRESS_SCRAPY_SETTING)
```

output:

```
SUPERSECRETIPADDRESS
```

---

**Note:**  Make sure that the `.env` file is in the same directory as the settings.py file or it is in one of it's parent/ancestor directories.

So if your settings.py file is in

- `/home/username/scrapy_project/scrapy_project/settings.py`

then that means the `.env` file can be in one of the following:

- `/home/username/scrapy_project/scrapy_project/.env`
- `/home/username/scrapy_project/.env`
- `/home/username/.env`
- `/home/.env`
- `/.env`

Otherwise it will not be able to find the file.

Comment: Ok but how do you use it inside a spider?

Comment: @rom The exact same way....  If you included the code you are attempting to use it in, or your previous attempts at trying it would be much easier to show you....

Comment: After discovering that my Python 3.9 installation was rejecting python-dotenv and even claiming it was not a module, I resolved the issue by creating a fresh virtual environment with Python 3.8. Your code then successfully executed. Thank you very much for your assistance!